# How to run a js scrip only after an element exist in a single page application?

Tags: javascript, routes, jquery-selectors, fetch, single-page-application

I have a single page application that I am using fetch API to render different pages, i.e. an photo gallery page. 
The SPA has an `index.html` and a navbar with an anchor tag for the photo page. And on click, the `body` tag in the `index.html` will be inserted with the content in the `photo.html` file.
The `photo.html` file has the following content:

```
<div>
  <img src="#" >
  <img src="#" >
  <img src="#" >
</div>
```

In my JavaScript, I want to add an event listener to each of the `img` tag in the `photo.html`, but the script got run immediately when the browser loads `index.html` and when I click on the anchor tag for `photos` to load the photo page content, `document.querySelectorAll("img")` return an empty array.

I was wondering if there's a way I can `document.querySelectorAll("img")` only after those `img` tags has been loaded.

Sorry if this question is a bit peculiar.

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, you could run the query after your fetch has completed. Or use event delegation where you listen for an event on, for example the `document` element. Add your JavaScript that is relevant to this question, or even better, make a snippet we can check out. Look for the `<>` icon in the toolbar of the editor on this site.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up defining a global variable after fetch is finished. @EmielZuurbier